# Gmail API Cannot Read Emails Sent Using SMTP Protocol

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail, gmail-api

I am having trouble reading emails that were sent using SMTP.

For example: When I send an email with the contents of `This is an email test` through a python file, It does not show when reading the emails from the API.

However, when I send the same email from the actual Gmail website, it shows up when I read from the API, giving me the body.

Is there a reason why Gmail cannot read emails that were sent using SMTP?

The email showed up in the inbox section at the website for both tests, but the one sent by Python did not show up in the console.

For sending:

```py
def send_email(subject, body):
            global host, app_password
            msg = MIMEText(body)
            msg['Subject'] = subject
            msg['From'] = host
            msg['To'] = host
            with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp_server:
                smtp_server.login(host, app_password)
                smtp_server.sendmail(host, host, msg.as_string())
```

For reading:

```py
def get_messages():

    # Verify Credentials and Token 
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'): 
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)  
    if not creds or not creds.valid: 
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token: 
            creds.refresh(Request()) 
        else: 
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('C:\\my\\path\\to\\credentials\\credentials.json', SCOPES) 
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0) 
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token: 
            pickle.dump(creds, token) 
  
    # Connect to the Gmail API 
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds) 
    result = service.users().messages().list(userId='me').execute() 
    messages = result.get('messages') 
  
    # Loop through emails
    try:
        for msg in messages: 
            txt = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=msg['id']).execute()  
            payload = txt['payload'] 
            headers = payload['headers']

            # Extract values from data
            for d in headers: 
                if d['name'] == 'Subject': 
                    subject = d['value'] 
                if d['name'] == 'From': 
                    sender = d['value'] 
            parts = payload.get('parts')[0] 
            data = parts['body']['data'] 
            data = data.replace("-","+").replace("_","/") 
            decoded_data = base64.b64decode(data) 
            soup = BeautifulSoup(decoded_data, "lxml") 
            body = soup.body() 

            # Output
            if sender=='Bote <'+host+'>':
                print(subject)
                if subject==code:
                    print(body[4:-5])
        if back==True:
            return
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: did you check in `Gmail website` if you get mail from `SMTP` ? Maybe `GMail` didn't get it, or maybe it puts it in folder with spam.

Comment: I did, It showed up in the website and did not show up inside the program. It was in the normal inbox folder and there was no indication of it being marked as suspicious and/or spam.

Comment: so I have no idea what makes problem. Maybe API gets data from different server and it doesn't have all information - and it needs time to update data. But frankly, I have no idea.

Comment: @furas Thanks for the help anyway! Is it possible that you could provide me with a different way to send emails with Python? The only method that I know of is SMTP as of now.

Comment: as I know you can send only using `SMTP`.  But I wonder why you check `if sender=='Bote <'+host+'>':`. Maybe this is your problem. Escpecially if you use `msg['From'] = host`, not `msg['From'] = "Bote <" + host + ">"`. Maybe first you should print all mails and see what sender is in mails

Comment: I used `if sender=='Bote <'+host+'>':` to check if the email was sent by the host. The host sends emails to itself and reads it if it was sent from the same email. There is no other email that it is sending and reading from. Additionally, it uses `d['From']` and it results in `"Bote <" + host + ">"`. Do you think that because it is not coming from another source it is unable to read it?

Comment: first I would use `print( sender )` to check what you really have in `sender`. And `print( 'Bote <'+host+'>' )` to check if it compare with correct value. Or even `print( sender == 'Bote <'+host+'>' )`